# PGPOOL Load Balancing: Create Sequence is going to replica

Tags: postgresql, sequence, pgpool

I created a pgpool instance which can connect to one master database(primary for write) and one read replica.

I have enabled below parameter:

```
disable_load_balance_on_write='dml_adaptive';
```

Now my below command fails when connect to pgpool :

```
create sequence if not exists public.xyz;
ERROR: cannot execute CREATE SEQUENCE in a read-only transaction
```

I am surprised "CREATE" statement is getting load balanced to replica. Anybody can throw some light here please?

Answer (score 0):

The primary *wal_level* value was *logical* and changing it to streaming replication i.e., wal_level=replica, made it work.

Comment: I don't understand why wal_level being *above* replica should make a difference.  It seems like you have found a bug in pgpool.